# Firebase Storage Rules strange behavior

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Based on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/core-syntax#granular_operations), Firebase Storage Rules version 2 can be writen with granular operations.

> A read operation can be broken into get and list. A write rule can be
> broken into create, update, and delete.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // A read rule can be divided into read and list rules
    match /images/{imageId} {
      // Applies to single document read requests
      allow get: if <condition>;
      // Applies to list and listAll requests (Rules Version 2)
      allow list: if <condition>;

    // A write rule can be divided into create, update, and delete rules
    match /images/{imageId} {
      // Applies to writes to nonexistent files
      allow create: if <condition>;

      // Applies to writes to existing files
      allow update: if <condition>;

      // Applies to delete operations
      allow delete: if <condition>;
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Supose I have some rules like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /randomFiles {
            allow get, create: if true;
            allow list, update, delete: if false;
        }
    }
}
```

Based in the official documentation, with this rules I can:

1. Upload new files, if don't have any with the same id. (writes to nonexistent files)
2. Get a single document.
3. I can't update, delete or list any existing file.

These assuptions are right?

Because now, I have a strange behavior:

Using this rules, I can override existing files. This is a bug?

In my client if I upload a file and after that upload a new file using the same reference, the rules agree with that. Thus, override the first uploaded file.

The Minimum code to reproduces the aplication using `Flutter 2.0` (stable channel) and `firebase_storage` 8.0.0

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

const FILES_DIR = "filesDir";

void main() async {
  //
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MyApp());

  await uploadFiles();
}

Future<void> uploadFiles() async {
  //
  var firstfile = File('lib/someimage.png');
  var secondFile = File('lib/otherImage.jpeg');

  Reference dirRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(FILES_DIR);

  var firstTask = await dirRef.putFile(firstfile);
  assert(firstTask.state == TaskState.success);

  var secondTask = await dirRef.putFile(secondFile);
  assert(secondTask.state == TaskState.success);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  //
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Container(
        child: const Center(child: Text("Minimum Flutter aplication for test purposes")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the minimal code that reproduces this problem too?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated with minimum code to reproduce the bug. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: My guess is that `update` only covers updating the file metadata, but let me check with some folks to see if I can get that confirmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `update` permission only applies to updates to metadata. It's hinted at in the reference documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#write):

> The `write` method covers all requests where file data or metadata is written, including file uploads, file deletes, and **file metadata updates**.

But that should definitely have been more explicit, so I filed a bug to get that updated.

---

You can implement your use-case already, but you'll do that through the `create` rule:

```
allow create: if resource == null
```

Let me know whether that works or not.

Comment: Thank you a lot. With this documentation update the rules will be easier to understand! 